# Unwrapping Result object in SwiftUI from Kotlin Multiplatform Request

Tags: kotlin, swiftui, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor

I want to unwrap a Result object that is defined in a Kotlin shared module for a Kotlin Multiplatform Project in iOS and Android.

Kotlin definition of Result object:

```
sealed class Result<out T> {
        data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
        data class Error(val errorMessage: String) : Result<Nothing>()
        object Loading : Result<Nothing>()
    }
```

The Result is returned from an API response in Kotlin as Result.

```
class SearchAPI {


private val baseUrl = "https://api.example.com"

@OptIn(InternalAPI::class)
suspend fun getSearchResponse(): Result<SearchResponse>{
    val client = HttpClient() {
        install(HttpTimeout) {
            requestTimeoutMillis = 60_000 // 30 seconds
            }
        }
    try {
            val response = client.post(baseUrl) {
  ...
  return Result.Success(searchResponse)
}
```

In Kotlin I can unwrap a API response from Ktor like this

```
fun searchCounts() {
   viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
   val result = searchAPI.getSearchResponse()
    
   // Handle the result, e.g., update UI or show error message
   when (result) {
         is Result.Success -> {
                    val searchResponse = result.data
                    _counts.value = searchResponse
                    // Handle successful response

                }
         is Result.Error -> {
                    // val errorMessage = result.message
                    // Handle error
                }

          Result.Loading -> TODO()
                else -> {}
            }
        }
    }
```

However, when unwrapping it in SwiftUI using switch clause, I get the error

> "Reference to member 'success' cannot be resolved without contextual
> type.".

And same for `Error` and `Loading`. Can someone show me how to use the Result object in SwiftUI?

This is the code with the error SwiftUI:

```
func searchCounts() async {
  do {
     let result = try await searchAPI.getSearchResponse()
     // Handle successful response
     print(result.self)
      switch result {
          case .success(let searchResponse): // Error Message
             self.counts = searchResponse
             // Handle successful response
           case .failure(let error):  // Error Message
                // Handle error
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
           case .loading():  // Error Message
                print("Error:")
                    }
        } catch {
            // Handle error
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

My multiplatform approach in general works, so I can print the body of the Kotlin API Request as JSON from SwiftUI, I just can't handle Success and Error states.

Comment: Checkout SKIE (https://skie.touchlab.co/) for better iOS developer experience in KMP. It's open-source.

Comment: Thanks, I added  id("co.touchlab.skie") version "0.6.1"
 to my gradle file but that didn't fix it.